# warning: title is "number-ranges", offset at (character 0, 0, 0)

Tags: gnuplot

I get a warning printed to stderr when I run gnuplot; however, as far as I can tell the plot generated is completely correct.   Can someone help me eliminate the warning?  The warning looks like the following.

```
title is "number-ranges", offset at (character 0, 0, 0)
```

I'm reading http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node275.html
for information of the syntax of the title command.

Here is a sample gnuplot input file.

```
# summary number-ranges
set term png
set key below
set title "number-ranges"
show title
set logscale xy
set style line 5 linewidth 1 linecolor rgb "#008941"
set style line 6 linewidth 1 linecolor rgb "#006fa6"
plot    "-" using 1:2 with lines ls 5 title "bdd-decompose-types-strong",\
   "-" using 1:2 with lines ls 6 title "bdd-decompose-types-weak" 
#008941 BDD-DECOMPOSE-TYPES-STRONG
24 2.0000001e-4
25 2.0000001e-4
42 0.0029090906
48 0.0033076922
end
# 006fa6 BDD-DECOMPOSE-TYPES-WEAK
16 1.25e-4
20 1.4285716e-4
30 4.545455e-4
36 7.5000006e-4
48 0.0013846154
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is exactly what the `show title` in your script does

```
set title "number-ranges"
show title
```

For whatever reason you are using it, if you don't need it ;)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know show title was showing the title on stderr, I thought it was showing the title in the plot.  After all that's part of the instruction I found on http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node275.html.  That it's printing the title to stderr, is truly bizarre.

Comment: That's the style of the gnuplot manual, showing the `set`, `unset` and `show` syntax of one option together